# Stop music when other media plays in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am trying to make an audioplayer app. I am using the AudioPlayers plugin.

I want the music to stop when other media, i.e. Spotify or a video on Facebook is played.
At the same time, I want the music to continue when the screen is turned off or the app is no longer in focus.

I'm using the following piece of code right now:

```
@override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    if (state == AppLifecycleState.paused) {
      _musicPlayer.player.stop();
    }
  }
```

But AppLifecycleState doesn't seem to have a state that helps me. Right now it will continue playing when the screen is off, but not if other media is playing.